# On editing event , how to check if in the dropdownlist cell was selected a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a gridview , with the following columns:
I've transformed the column cell into a dropdownlist via the edit template and added 2 items : Yes and No

```
NAME|AGE|Birthday|Code
Joh  21   12.12.2 Yes/No
```

there are 2 columns set = false; on page load.
I want to check on the row editing event from the gridview if the dropdownlist value == Yes then the 2 columns.visible = true;
I don't know how to do do the check thing..:(

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking how to find the control in the grid, or how to check the value of the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing it, we seem to have come up with this answer, using an OnSelectedIndexChanging event from the Yes/No DropDownList, instead of the Row Editing Event:

GridData is the ID of the GridView itself.

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList id = (DropDownList)sender;
    GridViewRow row = GridData.Rows[GridData.EditIndex];
    if(id.SelectedValue == "Yes")
    {
        TextBox column1 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Column1ID");
        column1.Visible = true;
        TextBox column2 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Column2ID");
        column2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: can't access IDofGrid ,it doesn't exist

Comment: what's with the grid data? :-? I dont have any griddata

Comment: hmm I get : Object reference not set to an instance of an object ( here: if ( id.selectedvalue == "Yes")

Comment: hi , if you are there, can you tell me please , if I check if he selected the value Yes , the dropdown value will be Yes instead of the default value No , because it has value No and Yes ( where No is the first value in the dropdown) and If I select yes my code will execute but the dropdown will be No.